# What is best practice to handle Core Data relationship if I don't have the full data-set?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have two type of models in the application I'm working on: `User` and `Account`.

Every account has many users. Every user has one account.

When I download the user object from an API, I get the `account_id`, but not the actual account object. The account object will be downloaded after the user object.

What is the best practice for establishing the relationship between the user and his account in this situation?

Should I insert an empty row into the Accounts table with just its `account_id` field filled in? And then later, when I download the account, update that row?

Comment: That is entirely up to you...

Comment: @Wain, I've edited the question. It now asks what the best practice for this situation is.

Comment: `Users` should be `User` and `Accounts` should be `Account`...

Comment: What type of relationships are you trying to achieve? What you mean with *Every account has many users. Every user has one account*? I would expect that each user can have zero or more accounts and each account is related to a specific user. Hence, a to-many relationship. Is this the scenario?

Comment: Not exactly. Every user has exactly 1 account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Core Data centric definitions, you have 2 entities (`User` and `Account`) and no tables (because this is an object store, not a SQLite database).

So, you wouldn't have empty rows, you would have stub objects (partially complete objects that will be filled in later).

There is no best practice when it comes to stub objects. Whether you should create them is entirely dependent upon your use case. In some cases it helps to have the basic information about an item so that you have something to show the user while you go and get the details. In your case, you only have an identity so the benefit of stub objects seems very low.